# An update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. The object SPE ncryptedString when try to change the farm account password

Tags: 2010

In SharePoint multi-server farm I updated the farm account password and run the below command from one app server where central admin site running when I try to run this command from another app server wfe server I got the below error

```
stsadm -o updatefarmcredentials -userlogin domain\account -password password
```

> An update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. The
>   object SPE ncryptedString Name=-4e8a-af3a-bf49012fccab was updated by
>   xxxxx/xxx, in the STSADM (4276) process, on machine AP01.  View the
>   tracing log for more information about the conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `updatefarmcredentials` operation **must** be run on the server that hosts Central Administration, and you got this error because you have tried to run The `updatefarmcredentials` operation on another App server / WFE server that **not host** the Central Administration.

For more details check [Updatefarmcredentials: Stsadm operation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262150(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: yes but in another servers sharepoint timer service stoped and it running with spfarm account, i have many application servers and wfe servers , is i should i go to each server to correct the password manually?

Comment: and also in wfe servers IIS security toke service application pool stopped how i update this without correct manually?

Comment: This command is specifically for 2007 meanwhile , I advise you to set farm account password via SharePoint PowerShell for SharePoint 2010/2013 farm by using Set-SPManagedAccount -Identity $username -ExistingPassword $newpassword  -UseExistingPassword:$true to update the relevant services and IIS pools. please tell me the result and don't hesitate to tell me if you need further clarification

Comment: Also,if you tried to change the farm password ,  this link is very useful https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mbakirov/2016/07/29/changing-sharepoint-farm-passwords/

Comment: Hi thanks, i used stsadm -o updatefarmcredentials -userlogin domain\account -password password  local in another servers except where central admin running, and above link also use ful to update the passwords for managed accounts